# How to run commands, get output and input commands with bash

Tags: bash, shell, command

How would I run a command (this is a command line Java app), read its output, and enter input into it, with a shell script. Is that possible? I heard about something called GNU Screen, but when I search with Google for it, it looks like something that won't help me? I am very confused. *So* basically 
I need to run a command, get its output, send send it input. Note: You need to input 'exit' to stop the command, *so* yes. I am confused here. Pointing me to a tutorial and explanation of GNU Screen or showing me something would be helpful.

Comment: Ummm, i need to 1 run the program 2 read the output it would give from a shell window 3 input like you would in a terminal window. How can i do that is shell/bash, if i can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is **[Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)**, "[...] a tool for automating interactive applications such as telnet, ftp, passwd, fsck, rlogin, tip, etc." using the [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/) scripting language.

However, **if no command you send to the program depends on previous output** of the same program, Bash might work well enough by itself; just use temporary files and I/O redirection (as in Usman Saleem's answer):

- Save a list of commands into a first file; and
- Redirect the program's standard input to that file; and
- Redirect the standard output to a second file.

The `read` built-in command may prove useful for reading the generated output file.

**GNU screen** is just a "terminal multiplexer" program that a) lets you have multiple terminal "windows" over a single modem or SSH connection and b) allows you to keep programs running even after you disconnect from a server. It is not the program you are looking for.

**One thing I would advise against** is making your shell script both generate the program's input and accept the program's output in real time; data will get caught in the stdio output buffers, and deadlocks can happen. This is why Expect was created.

Answer (score 1):

Use input output redirection. For instance,

```
java yourprog args > output.txt 2> erroutput.txt < input.txt
```

input.txt will contain the strings that you would enter on command line. System.out.println will go to output.txt, System.err.println will go to erroutput.txt

Screen is just a virtual terminal emulator and it allows you to have multiple shells from a single shell screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to wait to input `exit`:

```
output=$(echo "exit" | java prog)
```